# Extending a spark list in Flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I need to create a custom component in Flex 4.5 by extending the spark list class. Basically, I want to add a new variable named "title" of type UIComponent. When this variable is set, I need to render it at the top of the list.

This would give me a list with a configurable title component that scrolls with the list. Should be simple but I can't figure out how it's done. I've looked all the way up the hierarchy of **spark.components.List** and **spark.skins.mobile.ListSkin** and read a few articles about skinning but all the tutorials are extremely simplified and don't show how to do something like this.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look into the following flex POC: [iOS Theme](http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/2011/06/ios-theme-for-flex-mobile-projects-proof-of-concept.html). There are multiple parts to the list, but you can download the example projects are on the page. The component is called the ListForm and there is a skin, an ActionScript component, and an Item Renderer. The IR is less important and you can create your own which matches what you need, but the ListForm.as file and the corresponding skin do pretty much what I gather you need.

Comment: You the man. Not only does this show how to solve my particular problem in a clear and fully functional example, it also has lots of other interesting tidbits to study and apply. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm just glad you were able to get the help you needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new skin; and add the title section above the DataGroup.

You don't need to extend the List class unless you want to add new properties related to your title.

This is exactly what we did for our [Mobile Flex DropDownList](https://www.flextras.com/MobileComponents/Samples/MobileDropDownList/).  Click the "Change Skins" button and select PopUpSkin 2.  Then open the drop down; you'll she list in the pop up w/ a header above the list and a cancel button below it.

In practice, it is odd to use UIcomponent directly.  Can you expand more on what you want to put in the title?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took a look at your example but when I view the source I can't see the source for **com.flextras.mobile.dropDownList.skins.DropDownListMobileSkin_PopUp_2**, which is where the action is. Also, the header that you add just stays fixed, whereas I would need a header that scrolls away when the user scrolls down the list. For example, take a look at the "Contacts" application on the iPhone. It has a header with a Search control inside that disappears when scrolling down.

Comment: @tom__26 The source is only available for those who purchase; the sample was only intended for referential purposes. I don't have an iPhone so can't offer specifics on it's implementation. A List only scrolls items in it's dataProvider; so you could add an element in the dataProvider for your "Title".  An itemRendererFunction could be use to render that w/ something other than your defaultrenderer.  Alternately, you may be able to work something out with a Scroller that contains a Group which contains your 'title' and a DataGroup.  Then it should scroll the 'title' away as you scroll.

Comment: Yeah, before this I tried exactly what you said: a Scroller, a Group, and Header + List inside (with verticalScrollPolicy set to "off"), but I ran into problems with that. I have another post regarding that question here on this site, no real solution yet. Regarding your suggestion: I tried extending ListSkin and putting this code:   `override protected function createChildren():void
  {
   super.createChildren();
   var headerList:HeaderList = hostComponent as HeaderList;
   if(headerList.header != null)
   {
    addChild(headerList.header);
   }
  }` But nothing shows up.

Comment: I actually said DataGroup; not List.  They are two different components.  A List has an embedded Scroller, a DataGroup does not.  That said; why not use MXML in your ListSkin instead o trying to create it in AS3?  MXML will be tons easier.  And your approach to adding children looks very convoluted.  A component should maintain it's own children, you should add children onto it's skin; not onto the hostComponent.

Comment: And I'll add that all of your other questions are marked as answered; so I'm not sure what other question you're referring to that doesn't have an answer yet.

Comment: I was referring to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272213/problem-with-scrolling-a-sparks-list-with-tilelayout-in-flex-4-5. I marked it as answered because he suggested to create a new component with a header component, which is what this post is all about :-) But, the original error is still unresolved. Anyway, your comment about adding components to the skin and not the hostComponent has lit up a few light bulbs in my head. I'm new to Flex so these concepts are still not so clear to me. I'll try and tackle it again. In the meantime I'll mark this as answered, thanks.

Comment: @om__26 My only other comment of the moment is that I strongly recommend against accepting answers that don't solve the issue addressed in the question.  Best of luck!